# Rails 3 routing based on constrains for a 2nd domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying to use a secondary domain on my app for shorter urls (i.e. app.com/name would redirect to myawesomeapp.com/items/name).

Using constrains i have this so far, but it is not working:

(note I'm testing it only on my staging server at the moment, so I'm specifying the subdomain as well)

```
match "/:name" => "items#show_by_name", :constraints => {:host => "app.com", :subdomain => "staging"}
```

And in items_controller.

```
def show_by_name
  @item = Item.find_by_name(params[:name])
  render :action => "show"
end
```

When I've pushed this to heroku, and tried it out - nothing happens. I just get a "this page cannot be found" error. I've restarted the app to make sure its nothing like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are confusing host with domain.

```
request.host      #=> staging.app.com
request.domain    #=> app.com
request.subdomain #=> staging
```

Comment: Try to use only host: `:constraints => { :host => "staging.app.com" }`